# Disable editText soft keyboard completely

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I'm writing a process for the user to choose his country. I've an edittext linked to adapter which showing all available options.

In my manifest i set the the activity to
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"

I need to disable the soft keyboard completely.

It works fine except in one condition. if the user perform a long click/press on the editText the keyboard is popping.

Is there a way to permanently disable the keyboard in a specific activity by using code or in the manifest?

my code:

```
editCountry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                picker = CountryPicker.newInstance(getString(R.string.select_counrty));
                picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "COUNTRY_PICKER");
                picker.setListener( new CountryPickerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSelectCountry(String name, String code) {
                        editCountry.setText(name);
                        picker.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

my manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".UserSettingPref"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"

            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
```

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want the user to be able to edit it, why not just use a `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

use following code to disable the OnScreen Keyboard.